# Postgresql - Multiplying the Values of One Column with the corresponding/same row "Sum" Column Values

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a table with data as follows:

[image]

I wrote the following query to sum up the value of "Quantity" by "Part Number" as below:

```
SELECT
"Part Number", "Price",
sum ("Quantity") as "QTY"
from "Table"
group by "Part Number", "Price"
order by "Part Number"
```

Now, I would like to add one more column in my query, which would display the result of multiplying the values of "Price" and "QTY", and want to name that column "Subtotal".

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
"Part Number", "Price",
sum ("Quantity") as "QTY",
"Price" * "QTY" as "Subtotal"
from "Table"
group by "Part Number", "Price"
order by "Part Number"
```

No dice.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just:

```
SELECT
    "Part Number",
    sum(Quantity) as QTY,
    sum(Quantity * Price) Subtotal
from Table
group by "Part Number"
order by "Part Number"
```

Note that I moved column `Price` from the `GROUP BY` claused to within the `sum()`. This handles the case when a part number may have not always have the same price.

Answer (score 0):

This below query worked for me

```
    SELECT
    "Part Number",
    sum("Quantity") as QTY,
    sum("Quantity" * "Price") as Subtotal
    FROM tableone
    GROUP BY "Part Number"
    ORDER BY "Part Number";
```

See the table created having sum dummy values

[image]

as my table name was tableone, I tried the following query

```
    SELECT
    "part_number",
    sum("quantity") as QTY,
    sum("quantity" * "price") as Subtotal
    FROM tableone
    GROUP BY "part_number"
    ORDER BY "part_number"
```

See the output below

[image]